# Unity IAP identify Restored item on ProcessPurchase method

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Is there a method or strategy to understand when ProcessPurchase was called from a restore item?

I'm looking both for iOs and Google

Comment: It's very old ok... but did you get any useful hint on that?

Answer (score 0):

Is here: 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPRestoringTransactions.html

```
/// <summary>
/// Your IStoreListener implementation of OnInitialized.
/// </summary>
public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
{
    extensions.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions> ().RestoreTransactions (result => {
        if (result) {
            // This does not mean anything was restored,
            // merely that the restoration process succeeded.
        } else {
            // Restoration failed.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the standard restore process... I ask about understand where ProcessPurchase was called for a restoring item...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help: https://unity3d.com/cn/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

relevant code is, which is from the code sample:

```
public void BuyNonConsumable()
{
    // Buy the non-consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either 
    // through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
    BuyProductID(kProductIDNonConsumable);
}
```